# Tomcat redirect taking user outside the domain

Tags: apache, tomcat

i have this config in my web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>welcome</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.me.util.WelcomeServletPublic</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>redirect</param-name>
        <param-value>/login/login.action</param-value>


    </init-param>
    </servlet>
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>welcome</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

in my development environment this redirect worked just fine.  now that everything is moved into my production environment, the redirect isn't working.

whats supposed to happen is when you go to https://mydomain.com it redirects you to https://mydomain.com/login/login.action

whats happing is its redirecting to https://login/login.action, its loosing the domain name

now the big thing that has me wondering where its going wrong is how my production server is configured.

at the front door, i have apache running mod_jk.  there are two listeners, 80, and 443.  the 80 listener is configured with mod_rewrite to take the http:// url and rewrite it to https://.  the 443 listener then takes the request and dumps it down to mod_jk which redirects the request to tomcat via port 8009.  tomcat is running about 6 applications, each in its own vhost.

ive never had to do a configuration quite like this and don't know where to being troubleshooting this.  i know i can't take the preceeding / out of the url in the servlet because then if someone went to mydomain.com/users, it would redirect them to mydomain.com/users/login/login.action, so i really don't know where to start.

here is my apache vhost config

```
    <VirtualHost 10.99.10.30:80>
        ServerName boardingsurvey.mydomain.org
        ServerAlias boardingsurvey.mydomain.org

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 10.99.10.30:443>
        ServerName boardingsurvey.mydomain.org
        ServerAlias boardingsurvey.mydomain.org
        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/bss
        <Directory "/var/www/vhosts/bss">
                AllowOverride None
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        JkMount /* bss

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXP56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/intermediate.crt
</VirtualHost>


~
```

Comment: has anyone tried to put a fully qualified domain name in the servlet mapper?  i suppose i can try that....

Comment: The problem will be in how you are constructing the redirect but since you haven't shown us that code, it is impossible to tell you what you have done wrong.

Comment: easy enough, give me a sec i will post the apache config

Comment: That is useful, but not what i asked for. I asked how is com.me.util.WelcomeServletPublic constructing the redirect from the parameter you provide.

Comment: OH, OOPS, you were right, the welcomeservlet was adding an addtional / to the URL.  thats what was messing up the rewrite, it seems to be working now.  thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full explanation of why this was happening is as follows.

By adding an extra '/' to the redirect, the path being used for the redirect was //login/login.action

This type of URL is often referred to as a 'protocol relative' URL although the correct name is 'network-path reference'. See RFC 3986. Section 4.2. The absolute URL used as a redirect is generated using <current-protocol>:<network-path reference> which in this case gives http://login/login.action

Network-path references are normally used to generate a redirect when you want to specify the host but don't know if the user agent is using http or https and the string passed to the redirect would be "//host:port/contextpath/servletpath/pathinfo". A strict interpretation of the Servlet specification 3.0 and earlier does not allow the use of network-path references for redirects. Servlet 3.1 will allow them and recent versions of Tomcat 7 allow them for Servlet 3.0 and earlier as well.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1299005/mark-thomas comment above was the problem.  my welcomeservlet was adding an additional / to the url and thats what was messing up my rewrite.